# Reading multiple strings from a file using one fscanf

Tags: c, file, scanf

So the idea is to read a file and put it in the fields of struct CARRO.

Thing is, when I try to `printf` a structure variable (`dados[1].marca` for instance), it doesn't show me anything in the console.

I really can't see where the problem is, since the fscanf actually returns 8 (8 successfully read variables).

The file I'm using is a list of cars, each line containing info about a specific model, and has the following format:

```
Ford[]Transit Custom Van 270L1 Econetic Base 2.2TDCi H1[\t]2013[\t]3[\t]2[\n]
(...)
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
   {
   char marca[50]; 
   char modelo[50];
   char ano[5];
   char lugares[5];
   char portas[5];
   }CARRO;

main()
   {
   FILE *fp=NULL;
   CARRO dados[4700];
   int i=0;

   fp=fopen("car.txt","r");
   while (fscanf(fp,"%[^ ] %[^\t] %[^\t] %[^\t] %[^\n]", 
         dados[i].
         marca, 
         dados[i].modelo, 
         dados[i].ano,
         dados[i].lugares,
         dados[i].portas)!=EOF);  
      {
      i++;
      }

   fclose(fp);
   }
```

Comment: Please add the wrong output you are getting as well.

Comment: my bad.. it was CARRO dados[4700]

Comment: `while(...);` : remove `;` and `fscanf(fp,"%[^ ]... ` change to `fscanf(fp," %[^ ]... `

Answer (score 0):

*See comments in code below:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
   {
   char marca[50];
   char modelo[50];
   char ano[5];
   char lugares[5];
   char portas[5];
   } CARRO;

int main()     // Changed to 'int' type.
   {
   FILE *fp=NULL;
   CARRO dados[4700];
   int i=0;
   int nCnt;   // Added this line for printing result.

   fp=fopen("car.txt","r"); //Should check fp here to ensure file was successfully opened.  
   while(fscanf(fp," %[^ ] %[^\t] %[^\t] %[^\t] %[^\n]\n", // Slightly modified to 'gobble-up' newlines.
         dados[i].marca,
         dados[i].modelo,
         dados[i].ano,
         dados[i].lugares,
         dados[i].portas)!=EOF)  // Removed semicolon. As per 'BLUEPIXY'
      {
      i++;
      }
   fclose(fp);

   /* Added to print result. */
   for(nCnt = 0; nCnt < i; ++nCnt)
      printf("marca[%s] modelo[%s] ano[%s] lugares[%s] portas[%s]\n",
         dados[nCnt].marca,
         dados[nCnt].modelo,
         dados[nCnt].ano,
         dados[nCnt].lugares,
         dados[nCnt].portas
         );

   return(0);  
   }
```